# Module not found: import rendertostring from "next-mdx-remote/render-to-string"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While starting a development server with `npm rund dev`, it returns me following error:

```
wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
error - ./src/lib/markdown/posts.ts:5:0
Module not found: Package path ./render-to-string is not exported from package C:\Users\Sarah\Code\revoic-marketing\node_modules\next-mdx-remote (see exports field in C:\Users\Sarah\Code\revoic-marketing\node_modules\next-mdx-remote\package.json)
  3 | import matter from "gray-matter";
  4 | import config from "@/config/config.json";
> 5 | import renderToString from "next-mdx-remote/render-to-string";
  6 | import { withTableOfContents } from "@/remark/withTableOfContents";
  7 | import { withNextImages } from "@/remark/withNextImages";
  8 | import mdxPrism from "mdx-prism";

Import trace for requested module:
./src/lib/markdown/index.ts
./src/pages/index.tsx

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

Answer (score 0):

The import path is incorrect in your code example. You are importing from `next-mdx-remote/render-to-string`, which does not exist.

Check out the [next-mdx-remote readme](https://github.com/hashicorp/next-mdx-remote#examples) for an example of how it's used and how to import it.